# Passing data/request to multiple html files

Tags: python, html, django, forms, view

Is there a way to pass data to multiple html files?

```
def topic(request, topic_id):

    topic = Topic.objects.get(id = topic_id)

    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')

    videos = topic.document_set.order_by('-upload_at') 

    images = topic.image_set.order_by('-upload_at')  

    context1 = {'topic': topic}
    context2 = {'entries': entries}



    return render(request, 'learning_logs/entry.html', context1)
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/text.html', context2)
```

I want the data to passed onto both html files, but only one is actually rendered/displayed.

The html file that is displayed will have an extends linking to the other one.

Comment: A function can only return one value. Your second return statement isn't being run because your function will have already returned something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to create a new template that includes the other two instead of making one extend the other:

**learning_logs/index.html**:

```
{% include 'learning_logs/entry.html' %}
{% include 'learning_logs/text.html' %}
```

**view**:

```
def topic(request, topic_id):

    topic = Topic.objects.get(id = topic_id)

    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')

    videos = topic.document_set.order_by('-upload_at') 

    images = topic.image_set.order_by('-upload_at')  

    context = {
        'topic': topic,
        'entries': entries,
    }

    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html', context)
```